# Access to XMLHttpRequest at '...' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, api, tomcat, cors, activiti

I'm trying to demo an api call with javascript to get Json result. Here is what I did:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
        <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div class="render-form">
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        headers:{    
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' 
                        },
                        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/activiti-rest/service/form/form-data?taskId=21159',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                        }
                    });
                })
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I run it, I got an error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/activiti-rest/service/form/form-data?taskId=21159' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

After searching many post in here, I added:

```
headers:{    
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' 
},
```

But it still not work with that error. How should I fix this?
Any reply would be very appreciate!
Thank you very much!

Comment: The `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' ` header must be added by the backend.

Comment: But this is a demo, I write in only 1 .php file. Anyway to fix it?

Comment: Could you post also your php file please?

Comment: I updated my post, that is all my code in a php file and I use xampp to run it.

Comment: You need to add the header to the server not the client https://enable-cors.org/server_php.html

Comment: What is the code that creates a response for your request at the "/activiti-rest/service/form/form-data" route?

Comment: it's a framework named Activiti, I use rest to get that response.

Comment: the receiving server should has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` allowing the requesting server url, the server who is receiving the request should know that this is the url i need to allow.

Comment: I don't know much about Activiti, but if it is your server side, and you don't have access to the code or the config of it, you will not be able to solve this.

Comment: I just remember! The Activiti framework run on my Tomcat. Can I fix any on Tomcat to fix this?

Comment: The question is, as frzsombor asked, can you change the code of your backend side or not? Do you have access to it?

Comment: **Danger**: jQuery 1.11.1 has known security updates and is unsupported. Upgrade to a supported version of jQuery.

Comment: @Tomato Have you been able to try what I suggested in my answer?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to reply your answer! I added filter in my web.xml in Tomcat but it's still not work. Currently I'm using Laravel and setup for Allow-Origin and it's work. I really don't know how to handle it with ajax

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the Activiti framework on Tomcat, you can config CORS support in Tomcat via a filter. You need to add this filter to your web.xml file and configure it to match your requirements.

Check Tomcat's documentation:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter

*Also please note:*

- *As @Quentin pointed out in a comment you are using a jQuery version that is 5 years old and dangerously out of date.*
- *The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header you are using in your ajax request is a **response header**, not a request header, so it should be returned by the server in the response. You can't use response headers in a request.*